# Performance of individual vs. total import

Tags: google-app-engine

I've started to obsess about imports relative to instance spin-up latency. Got me thinking...

I use a separate, central kinds.py module for all my Model.db class definitions. Different handler/task modules will import the classes they use from it. Was wondering about the tradeoffs of doing a global "import kinds" vs. a series of "from kinds import ...". If the entire kinds.py is not needed, is it faster to do the individual imports? Or, is the process python/GAE uses to work through the individual imports going to be faster? Maybe some break even point at n% of the global total exists?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in speed between these two options. Python has to parse the whole file anyway.

In fact strictly speaking, there might even be a difference in the other direction: with `from kinds import ...`, Python would have to create and assign each reference, which adds a (tiny, tiny) load.